# PyCharm: Unreachable Code?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, pycharm

PyCharm is showing me that some code is unreachable within a method before the return statement is reached. I cannot help but wonder how is that even remotely possible?

```
def post(self):
    # get the desired parameters
    username = self.request.get('user')
    password = self.request.get('pass')

    if not self.REGEX.match(username) or not self.REGEX.match(password):
        logging.debug('RegistrationHandler: Bad credentials ->', username, password)
        self.fail('bad username or password')

        print 'Blah' # <---- shows as UNREACHABLE ?
        return # <---- shows as UNREACHABLE ?
```

`self.fail` simply calls `self.response.write(things)`.

**Update:**

Yeah, when I surround it with a try/catch clause, the issue is resolved... Strange. (Note that the method doesn't *always* raise an exception.

Comment: When I change my method name from fail, the issue is actually resolved... Maybe PyCharm trying to do something interesting with `fail`? It think `fail` raises an exception?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I actually think this is a bug in PyCharm, thinking that `fail` refers to [`TestCase.fail`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.fail), which would in fact make the code unreachable.

If I use your example, but rename `fail` to for example `failure`, the errors disappears. I'd report this bug to the friendly folks at PyCharm to see if this is in fact the case.

Comment: I used failure when I mentioned that I changed it.. Interesting. I was really curious where that came from, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This code is unreachable less...

Inspection info: This inspection detects code which can not be normally reached.
import random
from typing `import List, Any`

```
while True:
x: List[Any] = list(str(random.sample(range(1001, 10000), 1)))
x.remove("[")
x.remove("]")

print(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

check the indentation of your function and the statement/line which is unreachable.

I used it like the second function is included in the first functions' indentation

[How the code should be when indentation removed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tS4OG.jpg)

then I removed the indentation before if statement and I got the result.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
You are Welcome!